# Getting large data: sqlconnection and compression

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I need to get around 50k-100k records from a table. Two of the fields hold very long strings. Field1 is up to 2048 characters and field2 is up to 255.

Getting just these two fields, 50k rows takes around 120 seconds. Is there a way to use compression or some how optimize the retrieval of this data? I'm using a data adapter to fill a data table.

Note: It's just a select statement, no where clause.

Comment: What indexes exist on that table? How long does the query take when you execute it via SSMS?

Comment: How are you using those records?  I think that your best bet is to change the way you are processing so that you do not need to pull all of the records in one query.  The best way to go about this would depend upon what you are doing with the records.  An you add a little detail?

Comment: The records need to be pulled down and processed but depend on data from other rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: DONT PULL 50.000 to 100.000 rows. Point. Mass transfers always take time, and compression would put a lot of stress on the cpu. I still have to come to a case where pulling that much data outside of pure data transfers is a worthwhile proposition - most of the time it is a sign of a bad architecture.

Comment: I +1 that. I'll try to figure out another way.

Comment: data size don't correlate with architecture so your statement is based on wrong assumption